# Specify specific worker configuration in GCP Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to specify the configurations I want for a single dataflow worker? It seems like the default contains 4 cores and 15GB of memory, which is more than enough. How can I down size it or is this the smallest unit of a worker being offered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Workers section](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#python_3) of the Dataflow > How-to Guides > Deploying a Pipeline page, you can specify a custom machine type (with different cores or memory) with the `--worker_machine_type` option.

You can also see the other Dataflow worker-related options in the [docs/source code](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/_modules/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.html#WorkerOptions) for the `WorkerOptions` class, which parses the various worker-related command-line options. Some of the other options listed here include: `disk_size_gb`, `worker_disk_type`.

Tangentially related: Additional GCP-related Dataflow options are handled by the [GoogleCloudOptions](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/_modules/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.html#GoogleCloudOptions) class.

Comment: The source code was incredibly helpful, thanks!